# ruby on rails tutorialでgitにpushできるようにしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bitbucket

お世話になります。初心者のため質問方法が不適切かもしれませんが、下記をご教示願えないでしょうか。

AWSのcloud9にて、ruby on rails tutorialを始めたのですが、第一章の1.4.3のBitbucketで、下記エラーメッセージが発生しGitにプッシュできず困っております。

具体的にはターミナルにて以下の通り入力

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org：goshima / hello_app.git
```

→下記の通り表示される。

```
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from」
```

次に、`git push -u origin --all` と実行すると、下記のようなメッセージが表示されております。

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

過去質問も検索しましたが、該当するものはなく、cloud9の環境？も２回全削除してトライしておりますが、上記エラーメッセージのままです。。お手数で恐縮ですが、どなたかご教示願えないでしょうか。

Comment: コロンが全角になっているところや、スラッシュの前後にスペースが入っているところは、そのまま打ちましたか？　実際には半角だったりスペース無しでしょうか。

Comment: ユーザー名を少し加工して載せてしまったので、全角が混じっておりましたが、Bitbucketに表示されているコードにスペースが入っておりました。当該スペースを削除してチャレンジしたところ、１個目のエラーが消えました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

1つ目のコマンドを実行した後に表示されているのは、コマンド (`git remote`) の **実行方法(ヘルプ)** です。

ヘルプをよく見ると `add` の後には `<name>` と `<url>` にあたる引数が必要ですが、あなたの実行したコマンドでは余計なスペースが含まれていたりするため、引数の数が合わなくてエラーとなり、ヘルプが表示されている状態です。

(恐らくあなたが) 参照されている [チュートリアル](https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=5.1#sec-bitbucket) に載っているコマンドの実行方法は以下の通りです。

```
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:ユーザー名/hello_app.git
                 ~~~~~~
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <name>                    <url>
```

`<name>` と `<url>` にあたる部分には基本的にスペースは含めないので、実際のコマンドに置き換えるなら以下の通り実行する必要があるはずです。
nekketsuuu さんがコメントで指摘している通り、コロンも半角なので注意してください。

```
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:goshima/hello_app.git
```

Comment: cubickさんとnekketsuuuさんがご指摘してくださった事項を訂正した結果、１つ目のエラーが消えました！ありがとうございます！


ただ恐れ入りますが、２つめのコード「git push -u origin --all」を入力したところ、新たに下記エラーが引き続き出てしまうのですが、こちらも大変恐縮ですが、ご教示願えないでしょうか。。

「fatal: 'git@bitbucket.org：gorishima5656/hello_app.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.」

Comment: 過去の質問履歴を探してみたところ、下記サイトに近いのかなと思ったりもしておりますが、そちらの判断もなかなかつかない状態です。
https://teratail.com/questions/119026

Comment: チュートリアルの手順に従って、あらかじめ bitbucket 側にリポジトリの作成や公開鍵の登録は済ませていますか？

Comment: 予め前提事項として記載しておらず申し訳ございません。
リポジトリの作成や公開鍵の登録は済ませております。tutorialに加え、下記サイトのコードとも照らし合わせて実施してきたので、コードの漏れやディレクトリ間違い（hello-appで実行）もないかと存じます。

Comment: レポジトリや公開鍵に問題がありそうとのことなので、当該事項に関して、まずは自分でネット検索し解決方法を色々と試してみます。大変失礼いたしました。
誠にありがとうございました！